# Ionic 4 <button ion-item> not showing properly

Tags: html, list, ionic-framework

I'm aiming for a page where there's a searchbar along with a list of items that are clickable. I’ve been using the code that’s in ionic docs to make it happen but it's not giving me the right result.
This is the code:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Page</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemSelected(item)">
      {{ item }}
      </button>  
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Yet when I look at it on the app it shows the items like normal buttons, like this:
https://puu.sh/BNGId/d21ea0ef34.png

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I am aiming for it to look like shown here https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#list-lines

Comment: `<ion-button>` my friend.

Comment: @SimãoGarcia that's not what i'm aiming for and it is not the intended result. I am aiming for this https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#list-no-lines particular kind of list.

Comment: You're missing `no-lines` on the list?

Comment: Sorry actually meant it to be this https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#list-lines

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually solved the issue, it should be:

```
<ion-item button *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemSelected(item)">
  {{ item }}
</ion-item>
```

Looks like the folks at Ionic made a mistake?

Comment: Worked for me 